# Yii framework - nested modules

Tags: module, yii

I am trying to define nested modules, but I couldn't find any complete explanations in the tutorials.

I have a module `admin` and I want to add another module inside it `imgManager`, here is my directory structure:

```
protected
    ...
    modules
        admin
           ...
           modules
                imgManager
           ...
    ...
```

I defined the nested modules in my main config file like this:

```
'modules'=>array(
    ...
            'admin'=> array(
                'modules'=>array( 
                    'imgManager' => array(
                        'import'=>array('imgManager.*','imgManager.components.*'),
                        'layout'=>'application.views.layouts.column1',
                        'upload_directory'=>'gal_images',
                        'max_file_number' => '10',//max number of files for bulk upload.
                        'max_file_size' => '1mb',
                          ),
                    ),
            ),      
),
```

And here is my urlManager:

```
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
                     'admin'=>'admin',
                     'admin/<controller:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>',
                     'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
    ),
```

I need to access to this nested module like this: `mydomain.com/admin/imgManager` but I get `Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "admin/imgManager".` Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to define the module also in here:

```
class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{
     public function init()
     {
           ...
           $this->setModules(array('imgModule'));
         }
         ...
}
```